# Emulating printf stack popping

Tags: c, winapi, x86, printf, emulation

I'm writing a X86 application level emulator on Win32 which emulates an executable program and hooks its API calls forwarding them to my callbacks.
In those callbacks I print some debug stuff and then call the actual API, each callback is something like:

```
int hook_MessageBoxA( emu_t *emu, mem_t *mem )
{
    char *pszText, *pszTitle;
    DWORD hwnd, text, title, button;

    // pop arguments from the stack
    STACK_POP(emu, &hwnd);
    STACK_POP(emu, &text);
    STACK_POP(emu, &title);
    STACK_POP(emu, &button);

    // read actual strings from process memory
    mem_read( mem, text,  &pszText, 256 );
    mem_read( mem, title, &pszTitle, 256 );

    printf( "* MessageBoxA( %p, %s, %s, %d )\n", hwnd, pszText, pszTitle, button );

    // call the real API
    int ret = MessageBoxA( hwnd, pszText, pszTitle, button );

    // store return value into EAX register
    emu->regs->eax = ret;

    return 0;
}
```

This is working flawlessly for every API, but I have problems hooking the **printf** API inside MSVCRT because I don't know how many arguments I have to pop from the stack besides the szFormat.
How can I determine the number of arguments I have to pop? How does the printf stuff works low level ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to pop `printf()`'s arguments if you didn't put them on the stack in the first place.

Regardless of calling convention, all variadic functions are caller-cleaned, so they read their arguments without popping them.

Comment: Ok, half of the problem solved, then how do I know how many args are pushed on the stack so I can just read them ( without popping, which is just a regs->esp += 4; ) and print them for debugging purposes ?

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli you have to do it the same way printf does - by examining the format string for its various % elements.

Comment: For that, I'm afraid the only way is to do as printf() does: parsing the format string. Keep in mind that `long long` and `double` arguments take two words, so you can't just count the unescaped percent signs: you actually have to read the format to determine the type.

Comment: seems legit :D I was already thinking about that solution but I hoped for a better/easier one :P tnx